# What will happen when lightning strikes a zeppelin?

Tags: electricity, lightning

I know airplanes have an aluminium outer body that lets lightning just slide through the outer surface and not causing much damage. But what will happen in the case of a zepplin?

Comment: Do zeppelins even exist anymore? And if they did they wouldn’t be using hydrogen

Comment: They don't exist anymore, and even if they did they would be using helium as it's not inflammable. This was just a theoritical question out of curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Zeppelins usually use a conducting shell. Secondly, inside the hydrogen-filled shell there exists "no" oxygen. Hence, it is not possible to ignite a fire **inside** the shell. 
Nevertheless, Zeppelins fires have been observed during lightning strikes. However, this was during the landing procedure, when hydrogen is vented to increase the ballast.  The vented hydrogen mixes with the oxygen in the atmosphere, creating a combustible mixture.

Sidemark: One hypothesis for the famous German Zeppelin "Hindenburg" disaster is a lightning strike during the landing process.